# List of Lists Circular Definition Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of lists defined by integer:

```
val ex: List[List[Int]] = List(List (1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8 , 9), ex)
```

How can I multiply all the elements of the list of lists by two using circular definition in scala?

Edit:
A circular definition of an entity X is a definition that effectively uses X to set himself X.

Example:

```
val ex1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1,2,3), <call ex1 to multiply the elements by two>)
```

The example will create a list of lists infinite. I apologize for not having clarified earlier.

Thank you!

Comment: what is *circular definition*?

Comment: See the edited post, I'm sorry

Comment: I still do not understand. Please give the input and the expected output. I don't know what is a "list of lists infinite"

Comment: i would guess he means recursion

Comment: James, none of the answers was marked correct -- did they all miss the mark?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think you might be looking for Streams, which are like lazily defined Lists, and that definition can be recursive.  Does this look like what you want?

```
scala> val ex:Stream[List[Int]] = List(1,2,3) #:: ex.map( _ map (_*2) )
ex: Stream[List[Int]] = Stream(List(1, 2, 3), ?)

scala> ( ex take 5 ) foreach println
List(1, 2, 3)
List(2, 4, 6)
List(4, 8, 12)
List(8, 16, 24)
List(16, 32, 48)
```

or perhaps

```
scala> val ex:Stream[List[Int]] = List(1,2,3) #:: ex.map( _ map (_+3) )
ex: Stream[List[Int]] = Stream(List(1, 2, 3), ?)

scala> ( ex take 5 ) foreach println
List(1, 2, 3)
List(4, 5, 6)
List(7, 8, 9)
List(10, 11, 12)
List(13, 14, 15)
```

Comment: Ah, now I see that Luigi had given a two-part answer, and the second part was about Streams.  I'll leave mine, though, because we interpreted the problem differently, so our solutions are different.

Comment: ```val ex``` should be ```def ex``` to avoid circular reference

Comment: it's a compile error http://www.scalakata.com/5095b810e4b093f3524f3435 At least in the presentation compiler.

Comment: Guillaume, your question forced me to do some research; I wrote up the question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13217222/464309).

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to do this:

```
val ex: List[List[Int]] = {
  val ex = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
  ex ++ ex
}
```

This isn't a circular definition because the inner `ex` is just shadowing the outer one (and it's clearer if you use a different variable name).

If you actually want a recursive definition, you need to use a lazy data structure such as `Stream` (you can try it with `List`, but you'll get a `NullPointerException`). So you can write this:

```
val ex: Stream[List[Int]] = 
  Stream(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9)) #::: (ex take 3)

ex.toList // if it actually needs to be a List, which is probably doesn't
```

`#:::` is the lazy `Stream` equivalent of `:::` on `List`.

If you append `ex` rather than `ex take 3` then `ex` will be infinite, and you can get your list with `(ex take 6).toList`.

**edit**: after reading @AmigoNico's interpretation of your question (which is probably the correct interpretation - but who knows!), you can also do this using the `iterate` function, e.g.

```
List.iterate(List(1,2,3), 3)(_ map (_ * 2))
  // List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 4, 6), List(4, 8, 12))

// or if you want it infinte:
val xs = Stream.iterate(List(1,2,3))(_ map (_ * 2))
(xs take 3).toList
  // result same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't have an infinite `List` because it is not a lazy data structure in Scala and you'll inevitably run out of memory. But Scala has a lazy structure - `Stream`
2. What you're looking for is an `iterate` function. It is missing in the standard library, so here's an implementation inspired by [Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aiterate) (assuming you're using Scala 2.10):

   ```
   implicit class AnyFunctional [ A ] ( val a : A ) extends AnyVal {
     def iterate ( f : A => A ) : Stream[A] = a #:: (f(a) iterate f)
   }
   ```

   Having it in scope you'll be able to use it like that:

   ```
   scala> List(1,2,3) iterate (_.map(_*2)) take 3 toList
   warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
   res7: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 4, 6), List(4, 8, 12))
   ```