# Stream#filter Runs out of Memory for 1,000,000 items

Tags: scala, out-of-memory

Let's say I have a `Stream` of length `1,000,000` with all 1's.

```
scala> val million = Stream.fill(100000000)(1)
million: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> million filter (x => x % 2 == 0)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I get an `Out of Memory` exception.

Then, I tried the same `filter` call with `List`.

```
scala> val y = List.fill(1000000)(1)
y: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ...

scala> y.filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
res2: List[Int] = List()
```

Yet it succeeds.

Why does the `Stream#filter` run out of memory here, but the `List#filter` completes just fine?

Lastly, with a large stream, will `filter` result in the non-lazy evaluation of the entire stream?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators. It works with `def million = Stream.fill(100000000)(1)` as the post notes.

Comment: My guess is that the cells that comprise individuals values within a stream are larger in memory than the cells that make up individual elements within a list. Also, if you're in the Repl, and you allocated the list first, and _then_ the stream, you're setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: @KChaloux - No - my `scala` REPL crashed after the exception, so I had run `scala` again for the one-million List test. As a result of the exception, I would've expected `scala` to have released its resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overhead of `List` - single object (instance of `::`) with 2 fields (2 pointers) per element.

Overhead of `Stream` - instance of `Cons` (with 3 pointers) plus an instance of `Function` (`tl: => Stream[A]`) for lazy evaluation of `Stream#tail` per element.

So you'll spend ~2 times more memory on `Stream`.

You have defined your `Stream` as `val`. Alternatively you could define `million` as `def` - in this case after `filter` GC will delete all created elements and you'll get your memory back.

Note that only `tail` in `Stream` is lazy, `head` is strict, so `filter` evaluates strictly until it gets first element that satisfies a given predicate, and since there is no such elements in your `Stream` `filter` iterates over all your `million` stream and puts all elements in memory.

Comment: If I understand, `plus an instance of Function (tl: => Stream[A])`, then `Stream#filter` runs in a lazy fashion, yes?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: unfortunately no. It evaluates all initial `Stream`.

Comment: by `all initial Stream`, that means that `million.filter(x => x % 2 == 0)` will put the entire stream in memory, and then evaluate the filter predicate?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: it will `iterate` over `Stream` in `filter` method and put stream to memory element by element wile iterating over it. So not `and then`, but "simultaneously".

Comment: Thanks @senia. But, the docs {http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream} say `Returns all the elements of this Stream that satisfy the predicate p in a new Stream - i.e. it is still a lazy data structure. The order of the elements is preserved`. So, memory could spike when actually `filter`-ing each element, but, at the end, a `Stream` is output?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: you are correct, it *should* be lazy, but it evaluates strictly to get first element. And since there is no first element (for this predicate) it evaluates all initial `Stream`. In `Stream` only `tail` is lazy - `head` is strict.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult here, but I'm still not understanding `evaluates all initial Stream`. Since there's no `head #:: tail` in my predicate, the entire Stream will be read in memory? The fault, then, is with `my predicate`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: see [implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1131) of `fill` method. It creates a single instance of `Cons` with 2 arguments: element and instance of `Function`. When you calls `tail` on this object it creates a new `Cons` with new `Function`. When you iterates over `Stream` from first to last element it creates (and holds in memory) as many instances of `Cons` and instances of `Function` as many elements it contains.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: your predicate is `_ % 2 == 0`, but problem here is not your predicate. You just should not hold reference to the first element of your `Stream` as `val` (`val million`). There is a good explanation in `Stream` [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.Stream). Use `def`: GC will delete filtered out elements from memory.

Comment: What senia says about using def with Stream allowing GC to happen is true, but make sure you understand the performance implications of using def: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217222/should-i-use-val-or-def-when-defining-a-stream