# How to create sequence?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to come up with an endless Fibonacci sequence of numbers function, that passes two parameters. The parameters will set the first 2 elements in the sequence.

```
def fib(i: Int, j: Int): Stream[Int] = {
 case 0 | 1 => current
 case _ => Fib( current-1 ) + Fib( current -2 )

}
```

Comment: Recursive fibo is *very* inefficient.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils any ideas on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Well, since the def of a fibo number, as you clearly know, is `fn = fn-1 + fn-2` and you know the first two numbers, set them and loop through. I could show you in a few languages but scala isn't one of them. Just ditch the recursion and I bet it'll will come to you.

Comment: What's with all the Fibonacci questions recently?  Is there a class assignment that I missed? ;-)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Is that true with tail-recursion? I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do, however, you have to recurs in the other direction. You do not define the current element based on previous elements but your function receives the current arguments and calls itself with the arguments of the next value:

```
def fib(i: Int, j: Int): Stream[Int] = i #:: fib(j, i + j)
println(fib(0,1).take(10))
```

In contrast to the typical recursive definition, this is not quaratic but just linear, so it is quite efficient. (Streams are of course more complex than a simple while loop).

Comment: oops -- no!  Don't use `def` to define the `Stream`; use `val`!

Comment: Why? Because def is recomputed?

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, this kind of thing is usually done with a `Stream` to avoid recalculating the same values over and over. The straightforward way to create a `Stream` of Fibonacci numbers is

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: 1 #:: ( fibs zip fibs.tail map ( n => n._1 + n._2 ) )
```

But you can make a more efficient version of this kind of Stream by avoiding the zip, like so:

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = {
  def loop( h:BigInt, n:BigInt ): Stream[BigInt] = h #:: loop(n, h+n)
  loop(0,1)
}
```

Notice that these use `val`; [you generally DO NOT want to use *def* to define a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217222/should-i-use-val-or-def-when-defining-a-stream)!