# Recursive LazyList construction inside def gives error

Tags: scala, lazy-sequences

If I write the following everything works as expected:

```scala
object Working extends App {
  val whl: LazyList[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: whl
  (1 to 10) foreach {n => println(whl(n)) }
}
```

However, if I wrap my `LazyList` in a `def`:

```scala
object NotWorking extends App {
  def f(): Unit = {
    val whl: LazyList[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: whl
    (1 to 10) foreach {n => println(whl(n)) }
  }

  f()
}
```

then I get an error message

```
forward reference extends over definition of value whl val whl: LazyList[Int] = 1 #:: 2 #:: 3 #:: whl
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I am using Scala 2.13.5 with IntelliJ Idea, if this makes any difference.

Comment: It needs to be lazy inside a method, object vals are always lazy.

Comment: Local variables cannot refer to themselves normally, so they need to be declared lazy. Object fields aren't really lazy, but the code above should be safe to use because `#::` doesn't evaluate `whl` until necessary.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, changing `val` to `lazy val` indeed works

Comment: I retracted my close vote and cannot vote again, but does this answer your question? [Should I use val or def when defining a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13217222)

Comment: @user No, that is another question altogether (`def` vs. `val`)